# Парсер kml файлов на php

Tags: php, python, парсер, gps

Ребят, всем привет, помогите...

Есть файл kml - это по сути xml файлик, подобного содержания:[кликкликклик-пастебин](https://pastebin.com/KSGpDj4D)

Я раннее не работал с парсингом xml и мне нужна помощь:
Как вывести информацию о каждой точке(в примере их 3, а фактически их более 50)?
Принимать он должен точки в порядке от 1 до 100(это максимум, который используется), в плане если не находит точку с таким номером, то цикл вывода обрывается(так себе представляю).
Информация о каждой точке, это Имя(которое тут),координаты (которые тут)

Мне нужна только эта информация и вывод по типу:
Имя | Координаты \n

Но я не представляю, как это вот всё реализовать
Желательно на php,что бы я хотя бы понял что к чему, либо же python(но я там т*п, как пень).

Хелп ми...

Comment: посмотрите документацию по SimpleXML в пхп, там все достаточно просто.

Comment: Я на питоне взял библиотеку pykml, вроде добился требуемых результатов, но хотелось бы на php реализовать

Comment: Ну вам сказали что сделать-то, сделайте уже.